# Preserve prototypes in ADVANCED mode

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I need to compile my code with closure compiler in ADVANCED mode. I also need to keep prototypes of my objects in my application because I'm looping on Javascript objects prototypes. Trying to get both results in some ReferenceError when starting the application.

When compiling with ADVANCED mode, some prototypes are removed and replaced by a function that is using an object parameter in order to recover "this" keyword. This is due to [crossModuleCodeMotionNoStubMethods](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L425) attribute of CompilerOptions.java.

Example of code before compilation :

```
function MyClass() = { // Some code }
MyClass.prototype.someFunc = function() { // Some code calling someOtherFunc };
MyClass.prototype.someOtherFunc = function(someParam) { // Some code };
```

Example of code after compilation :

```
function MyCompiledClass = { // Some code }
MyCompiledClass.prototype.someCompiledFunc = function() { // Some code calling someOtherFunc }
function someOtherCompiledFunc(that, someParam) = { // Some code }
```

I first tried to use @this and @preserve JSDoc tags to solve the problem, without success. Using @export is not a solution, because functions will then keep their original names.

I've found two options to solve my problem for now :

1. Refactor the code as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277169/5398225)
2. Build a custom version of Closure Compiler as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36969711/5398225)

Option 1 will need to much modifications in my code and will make it less readable, if it's the only solution, I will have a go for this one.

Option 2 seems to be a nice workaround, but I've read that some changes on CompilationLevel.java may violate some core assumptions of the compiler. Can someone tell me if by modifying [setCrossModuleMethodMotion](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java#L191) from true to false, will it still respect all core assumptions of the compiler ?

I'm currently building a custom version of the compiler to check if the code is compiling properly, but even if the code is usable, I need to be sure it will be properly obfuscated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The specific optimization pass you are referring to is `DevirtualizePrototypeMethods`. The best way to block the optimization would be to use the `@nocollapse` annotation. It will allow your method to be renamed but not allow it to be removed from the prototype.

I'm not 100% sure it will work for this case, but if it doesn't it should and you can file an issue to have that fixed: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues

Comment: I've found after my post that it's `DevirtualizePrototypeMethods` that is causing me some troubles.
I've just tried to use `@nocollapse` but without success. I even described `@constructor` for the constructor and `@this` for the prototypes to link them with my constructor.

I've also checked compiler version : 20170218.0.0.

For now, my quickfix is setting `DevirtualizePrototypeMethods` to `false` in my closure-compiler custom version.


Because my code is proprietary, how can I help you to solve the problem ? I have no knowledge about closure-compiler except on the user side ;)

Comment: I can say that `@nocollapse` is working for Javascript objects properties, like `MyClass.myProperty`. But it is not working for attributes like `MyClass.prototype.myAttribute`. I just encountered the same problem with javascript objects properties and your solution works fine for it.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue then. `@nocollapse` is the proper way to block this optimization without also blocking renaming.

Comment: I will create an issue so. Do you know if there is a possibility to set closure compiler to not collapse prototypes and attributes without writing `@nocollapse`, for instance with a command option ? I'm asking because otherwise, I will have to write `@nocollapse` almost everywhere in my code :/ Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> You can export constructors and prototype properties in the same way.
>   For example:

```html
MyClass = function(name) {
  this.myName = name;
};
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  alert(this.myName);
};
window['MyClass'] = MyClass; // <-- Constructor
MyClass.prototype['myMethod'] = MyClass.prototype.myMethod;
```

As in https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3